# Find circumradius of an equilateral triangle of side 7$\text{cm}$

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, problem-solving, osculating-circle

[image]

I know that each length is 7 cm but how would I use that to work out the radius.

Thank you and your help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the centroid of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: I think the centre is 360 degrees?

Comment: https://www.topperlearning.com/answer/in-an-equilateral-triangle-prove-that-the-centroid-and-the-circumcentre-of-the-triangle-coincide/jjrlmx88

Comment: I can't access the website it says access denied.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: draw lines from the circle center to each triangle vertex & to the centers of the triangle sides.

Comment: I split the triangle to 5 right angle triangles each having a 60 degree angle.

Comment: @AspaeringStar7 I'm not quite sure how you split the triangle into $5$ right-angled triangles (I think you actually mean $6$) with each having a $60$ degree angle. Note my hint does something similar. Regardless, though, don't forget that $30-60-90$ degree triangle side lengths have a special ratio. Using this, I was able to quite easily solve your problem, and I believe you should be able to as well.

Comment: I don't understand I'm only in ninth grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Equilateral triangle in circle]

As shown above, let $O$ be the center of the circle, $r$ be the circle radius and $D$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Draw lines from $O$ to $A$, $B$ and $D$. Note $OA$ bisects $\angle BAC$, so $\angle OAB = 30^{\circ}$. Also, Since $OA = OB = r$, $\triangle AOB$ is an isosceles triangle, so $DO$ is perpendicular to $AB$, which means $\angle ODA = 90^{\circ}$. By the sum of angles in a triangle being $180^{\circ}$, this means $\angle AOD = 60^{\circ}$.

Note the length of $AD$ is half that of $AB$, so it's $\frac{7}{2}$ cm. Also, since $30^{\circ}$- $60^{\circ}$- $90^{\circ}$ triangles have side lengths in a ratio of $1:\sqrt{3}:2$ (e.g., see the [30°–60°–90° triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangle#30%C2%B0%E2%80%9360%C2%B0%E2%80%9390%C2%B0_triangle) section of Wikipedia's "Special right triangle" article), this means

$$\frac{AO}{AD} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \implies r = (AD)\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{7}{\sqrt{3}} \text{ cm} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: Is o in the middle of the triangle the centeroid?

Comment: Yes, the point $O$ is both the center of the circle and the centroid of the equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to help me. I finally understand. Thank You! :D

Comment: @AspaeringStar7 You're welcome for the help. I'm glad you now understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the triangle sine rule,

$$\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}=\frac{\sin C}{c}=\frac{1}{2r}$$

where $r$ is the circumradius. For the equilateral triangle of side 7,

$$r = \frac{7}{2\sin60} = \frac{7}{\sqrt3}$$